# How to initialize dynamically created large integer array to a specific integer in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created an array R like this:
`int * R = new int[n];`
where n takes a large value, say 100,000. I want to initialize all the integers of the array to 1 in C++. What is the best/fastest way to do this? Or, is looping through the whole array the only option?

Comment: @MatějPokorný memset works on bytes, it's not a general solution for filling an int array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`std::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) from STL:

```
std::fill(R, R + n, 1);
```

But I suggest you to use `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<int> R(n, 1);
```

Don't use `memset(R, 1, sizeof(int) * n)`, because it assigns 1 to each byte (not element) of the array.

Answer (score 8):

> "What is the best/fastest way to do this?"

In C++ you use `std::vector<int> R(n,1);` instead.

If you need the `int*` elsewhere, you refer to `R.data()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    R[i] = 1;
}
//don't forget to "delete[] R;"!
```

You can use vectors:

```
std::vector<int> R(n, 1);
```

But arrays and loops are best friends, in case you can't use vectors. Although the use of vector is recommended since manual deallocation is handled by the class.